# How to generate the links for a specific post in android firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-dynamic-links

Am developing a social media app with android and firebase. However, I want to be able to create dynamic links for each post when a user clicks on the share button. I mean when a user clicks on the share button they should be able to share a link that contains some details of that specific post so that when someone clicks on the link they can be taken to the post details activity if they have the app installed. Can someone help me

Comment: What have you tried so far to achieve that?

Comment: By Using Firebase Dynamic Links